# Using a map with user entered values from jTextField

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, maps, jlist

I am wanting to allow a user to enter 2 values from 2 separate text fields ( Country and Capital ) after entered they will hit "add" ( jbutton ) and this will add country to key and capital to value ) This will also need to add capital to a Jlist to be viewed.

This map will then be able to be searched using a separate textfield/jbutton that the user will search for the country and it will then select the capital from the jlist

Should I just use a hashmap? Order shouldn't really matter if its just going to be searched, or does it? Obviously if order doesn't matter hashmap would be best choice as it is more efficient.

Everything I've done with hashmap or seen online is entries already provided in code, not taking it from 2 textfields.

I just need a push in the right direction, I'm sure its very simple and I've just overloaded my brain thinking its more complex than it needs to be, thank you in advance

I'm using net beans and have created the GUI with netbeans in design

Comment: At this level, use whatever you're comfortable with

Comment: Thank you. How would I set it up to take the user entered values from jtextfields to add to the key/value of the hash map?